# Passing a id in append function in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
   I'm creating a chat box
```

when I click the datatable of the person it has to display chat box that shows the name of the person I clicked.

My problem is I can't display the name of single person and the append div is not working properly. When I click datatable, a chat box has to be open showing the name of the person

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/15IVxCynRBkeBJMqBMZa?p=preview)

```
       <div class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="ListController"> 

        <section class="content" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Visitors List</h3>
              <div class="box-tools">
                <div class="input-group">

                  <input type="text" name="table_search" 
      ng-model="query" class="form-control 
                  input-sm pull-right" style="width: 150px;"   
        placeholder="Search"/>
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">


            <div id="divID"></div>


                <table class="table table-hover" >
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Profile</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Reknown</th>
                </tr>
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in artists | filter: query |  
                orderBy: artistOrder:direction" id="table-cursor">
                  <td ng-click="AppendText($index)">{{item.name}}</a>
                </td><td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><span value=" 
               {{artists.indexOf(item)}}">
                  </span><img ng-src="images/{{item.shortname}}_tn.jpg" 
             width="35" height="35" alt="profile"></td>
                  <td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><h5>
            {{item.shortname}}</h5></td>
                  <td ng-click="AppendText($index)">11-7-2014</td>
                  <td ng-click="AppendText($index)">
          <span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                  <td ng-click="AppendText($index)">{{item.reknown}}
       </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </section>       
        </div>
```

```js
//controller
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'artistControllers' 
    ]);

    var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

     myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
     function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
     $http.get('angular/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.artists = data;
      $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
      $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
      });
      }
      ]);

       myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
       function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
       $http.get('angular/data.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.artists = ;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
 

       $scope.AppendText = function(idx) {
 
     $scope.userInfo = $scope.artists[idx];
        //alert(idx);
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
       myEl.append(//'<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<div class="col-md-3" id="chatboxcorner">' +
    '<div class="box box-warning direct-chat direct-chat-warning">' 
       +'<div class="box-header with-border">' +
       '<div class="box-tools pull-right">' +
       '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="3 New Messages" 
        class="badge bg-yellow">3</span>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
         <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>' +
       '<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="tooltip"   
        title="Contacts" data-widget="chat-pane-toggle">
       <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div></div><div>' +
     '<p>' + idx +'</p>
      <img ng-src="images/{{userInfo.shortname}}_tn.jpg" width="35"   
      height="35" alt="profile">' +
     '</div><div class="box-footer"><form><div class="input-group">' +
  '<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..."     
      class="form-control"/>' +
     '<span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">
         Send</button>' +
     '</span></div></form></div></div></div>'
     );     
     }
     });

      }
      ]);
```

```js
 // json file
 [{
    "name": "Barot Bellingham",
    "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
    "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
    "bio": "Barot has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy of"
  }, {
    "name": "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    "shortname": "Jonathan_Ferrar",
    "reknown": "Artist to Watch in 2012",
    "bio": "The Artist to Watch in 2012 by the London Review, Johnathan has"
  }, {
    "name": "Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
    "shortname": "Hillary_Goldwynn",
    "reknown": "New York University",
    "bio": "Hillary is a sophomore art sculpture student at New York"
  }, {
    "name": "Hassum Harrod",
    "shortname": "Hassum_Harrod",
    "reknown": "Art College in New Dehli",
    "bio": "The Art College in New Dehli has sponsored Hassum on 
    scholarship"
  }, {
    "name": "Jennifer Jerome",
    "shortname": "Jennifer_Jerome",
    "reknown": "New Orleans, LA",
    "bio": "A native of New Orleans, much of Jennifer's work has centered"
  }, {
    "name": "LaVonne L. LaRue",
    "shortname": "LaVonne_LaRue",
    "reknown": "Chicago, IL",
    "bio": "LaVonne's giant-sized paintings all around Chicago tell the "
  }, {
    "name": "Constance Olivia Smith",
    "shortname": "Constance_Smith",
    "reknown": "Fullerton-Brighton-Norwell Award",
    "bio": "Constance received the Fullerton-Brighton-Norwell Award for "
  }, {
    "name": "Riley Rudolph Rewington",
    "shortname": "Riley_Rewington",
    "reknown": "Roux Academy of Art, Media, and Design",
    "bio": "A first-year student at the Roux Academy of Art, Media, and "
  }, {
    "name": "Xhou Ta",
    "shortname": "Xhou_Ta",
    "reknown": "China International Art University",
    "bio": "A senior at the China International Art University, Xhou has "
  }]
  '
```

Comment: Please provide a plunker, I doubt any1 will find it easy to help from all this code...

Comment: I don't know why the plunker is not working, I am new to this  http://plnkr.co/edit/15IVxCynRBkeBJMqBMZa?p=preview